# Constantly read JSON database

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to constantly read a JSON-formatted js file so my page shows the changes of that file.

I want some content in my page to change everytime I change the database file within the directory.

***My files are***:

**objectoJSON.js**:

```
var rightFencer;
rightFencer = {"name":"Jorge ANZOLA","nacionality":"VEN","points":10};

var leftFencer;
leftFencer = {"name":"John DOE","nacionality":"USA","points":5};
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<center><p id="rightFencerName"></p><p id="rightFencerPoints"></p> - <p id="leftFencerName"></p> <p id="leftFencerPoints"></p></center>
<script src="objetoJSON.js"></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("rightFencerName").innerHTML = rightFencer.name;
    document.getElementById("leftFencerName").innerHTML = leftFencer.name;
    document.getElementById("rightFencerPoints").innerHTML = rightFencer.points;
    document.getElementById("leftFencerPoints").innerHTML = leftFencer.points;
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I thought about putting those two scripts into an infinite while loop so by the time I change the file in the directory, it'd change. But it didn't work.

Also, I thought about using `setInterval()` to run the scripts every few seconds, but I didn't know how to make it work.

As you can see, I'm a complete noob, so **ANY** idea would be very appreciated.

Comment: What environment do you have on sever side? In NodeJS you could use fs.watch for example - https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener Or it's localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "objectoJSON.js" is not a JSON file... it's a simple `javascript object`.

A **JSON** file would be something like this.

```
{
 "rightFencer":{
  "name":"Jorge ANZOLA",
  "nacionality":"VEN",
  "points":10
 },
 "leftFencer":{
  "name":"John DOE",
  "nacionality":"USA",
  "points":5
 }
}
```

What you are searching for is

**Ajax, Server Sent Events or webSockets**

Those update the pagecontent without the need to refresh the page or clicking something.
The following codes shows how to interact with each technology.
They have many advantages and disadvantages... to many to write right now.
ask specific and i can add that to the answer.

All the following examples are pure javascript and so don't need any type of library.They work with almost all new browsers... ios,android,windows also.

All the following examples could be adapted to work with a non properly formatted json file like that you posted. Look at the bottom.

**Ajax:**

*Client asks for data*

This updates the client every 30seconds.

```
function $(a){
 return document.getElementById(a)
}
function ajax(a,b,c){ // Url, Callback, just a placeholder
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;
 c.open('GET',a);
 c.onload=b;
 c.send()
}
function reloadData(){
 ajax('database.js',updateText)
};
function updateText(){
 var db=JSON.parse(this.response);
 $("rightFencerName").innerHTML=db.rightFencer.name;
 $("leftFencerName").innerHTML=db.leftFencer.name;
 $("rightFencerPoints").innerHTML=db.rightFencer.points;
 $("leftFencerPoints").innerHTML=db.leftFencer.points;
}
window.setInterval(reloadData,30000);//30 seconds 
/*setinterval is a very bad way to update stuff , 
especially with ajax.. there are many other ways to do that.*/
```

Ajax does not need any type of server if you read the JS file locally.
Also appendding it... but both examples are time based... and that is not good if you have many users online. WS & SSE allow you to update **each user individually** depending on the necessity.

**SSE:**

*Server sends data when needed*

This uses php to create a Server Sent Events Server
Also this updates the client every 30 seconds, but in this case the server updates the client. Using Ajax the client asks the server to update.

The php file "sse.php"

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); // specific sse mimetype
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // no cache
while(true) {
 if(/*something changes*/){
  echo "id: ".time().PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: ".$data.PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
 }
  ob_flush(); // clear memory
  flush(); // clear memory
  sleep(30);// seconds 
}
```

The javascript file

```
function $(a){
 return document.getElementById(a)
}
function updateText(e){
 var db=JSON.parse(e.data);
 $("rightFencerName").innerHTML=db.rightFencer.name;
 $("leftFencerName").innerHTML=db.leftFencer.name;
 $("rightFencerPoints").innerHTML=db.rightFencer.points;
 $("leftFencerPoints").innerHTML=db.leftFencer.points;
}
var sse=new EventSource("sse.php");
sse.onmessage=updateText;
```

**WebSockets:**

*Server sends data when needed, Client asks for data when needed*

webSockets is cool ... comunication is bidirectional. it is fast. but you need something like a nodejs server to be able to handle it properly.

```
function $(a){
 return document.getElementById(a)
}
function updateText(e){
 var db=JSON.parse(e.data);
 $("rightFencerName").innerHTML=db.rightFencer.name;
 $("leftFencerName").innerHTML=db.leftFencer.name;
 $("rightFencerPoints").innerHTML=db.rightFencer.points;
 $("leftFencerPoints").innerHTML=db.leftFencer.points;
}
var ws=new WebSocket('ws://YOURIP:YOURPORT');
/*ws.onopen=function(){ //those events are also aviable with sse
 ws.send('WS open!');//sending data to the server
};
ws.onclose=function(){
 console.log('WS closed!');
};*/
ws.onmessage=updateText;
```

**Adapting the js**

Ajax..

load the "objectoJSON.js" with ajax and evulate it ... but not using `eval()`. eval is evil. use `new Function()`

```
function updateText(){
 document.getElementById("rightFencerName").innerHTML = rightFencer.name;
 document.getElementById("leftFencerName").innerHTML = leftFencer.name;
 document.getElementById("rightFencerPoints").innerHTML = rightFencer.points;
 document.getElementById("leftFencerPoints").innerHTML = leftFencer.points;
}
(new Function(this.response+'\n updateText()'))();
```

or append the script every 30 seconds or whatever....
I don't write that example as it is the worst approach.

With 30 clients it means that you have to read the file from server evey second.
With SSE or WS you read it once and broadcast it to hundreds of clients.

**I suggest to fix your json file.**

if you have any other questions ask.

Comment: Thanks! That was a really especific answer. Do you have any better idea for what I want to do? (Updating in real time a section of a page. For scoring).

Comment: all big sites use websockets for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working with framework which supports websockets.
You could listen for a change in file using websocket.it may return change in data set like new record or update on any record, or using javascript/ajax call get latest content from server and update your HTML.

https://www.websocket.org/demos.html, see foreign exchange dashboard to see how websockets can be used for constantly updating data.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it now isn't scalable, testable or manageable.

You **really** don't want to save data on the server using plaintext json files.

If you want a more robust framework for handling your use case, I suggest using web sockets on both the client side and server side (socket.io is a great choice), and using RethinkDB on your server as the DB.